# Unclear whether professor will provide assistance after sending through CV and an essay

Tags: masters, etiquette, email

I am a graduate civil engineer and want to pursue to academic career in the same field. I have been in contact with a professor, entirely by email, since March and he is responding me since March very well. I want assistantship to pursue my MS degree from the professor.

About a month ago he told me to write an essay about a topic and also to attach my latest CV. I have written an essay and send it to him. Its been a month and I have not received a reply.

He have sent me his last email on September 21 stating that he has received my essay. Now I don't know whether he has decided to provide me an assistantship or not.

Now I don't know how to follow up whether he is willing to provide me an assistantship.